# How to explicitly invoke an object's init block?

Tags: kotlin

I have a class that looks something like the following. On line 7, I would like to invoke the `init` block directly, however this does not seem to be possible without using reflection.

```
object MyClass {
    var editor: Editor = getDefaultEditor()
        set(value) {
            field = value

            //Todo: figure out how to avoid duplicating init block
            project = editor.project!!
            document = editor.document.charsSequence.toString().toLowerCase()
            findModel = FindManager.getInstance(project).findInFileModel.clone()
            findManager = FindManager.getInstance(project)
        }

    var project: Project
    var document: String
    var findModel: FindModel
    var findManager: FindManager

    init {
        project = editor.project!!
        document = editor.document.charsSequence.toString().toLowerCase()
        findModel = FindManager.getInstance(project).findInFileModel.clone()
        findManager = FindManager.getInstance(project)
    }
}
```

But I need to have the `init` block in order to initialize the properties without instantiating, so if I replace the code inside the `init` block with `setEditor(getDefaultEditor())`, then the compiler will complain that, "Property must be initialized or be abstract". How do I avoid duplicating all the stuff inside `init`?

Comment: Hey. Accept some answer to make this community better :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `lateinit` to say to the compiler "I'll initialize that property later".

```
lateinit var project: Project
lateinit var document: String
lateinit var findModel: FindModel
lateinit var findManager: FindManager
```

Then you can omit initialization in `init` block and do it whenever you want.

A notice from the official documentation:

> The modifier can only be used on var properties declared inside the
>   body of a class (not in the primary constructor), and only when the
>   property does not have a custom getter or setter. The type of the
>   property must be non-null, and it must not be a primitive type.
>
> Accessing a lateinit property before it has been initialized throws a
>   special exception that clearly identifies the property being accessed
>   and the fact that it hasn't been initialized.

Comment: @Jacob It will :)

Comment: Thanks! What about if the property is a primitive type?

Comment: The easiest option it to wrap the primitive in a class ;)

Comment: for primitive properties - [`Delegates.notNull()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.properties/-delegates/not-null.html) + see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623177/kotlin-property-initialization-using-by-lazy-vs-lateinit

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it is possible to explicitly call the init block.

But I think this should do it for you:

```
object MyClass {

    var editor: Editor = getDefaultEditor()
        set(value) {
             field = value
             init()
        }

    lateinit var project: Project
    lateinit var document: String
    lateinit findModel: FindModel
    lateinit var findManager: FindManager

    init {
        init()
    }

    private fun init() {
        project = editor.project!!
        document = editor.document.charsSequence.toString().toLowerCase()
        findModel = FindManager.getInstance(project).findInFileModel.clone()
        findManager = FindManager.getInstance(project)
    }
}
```

But a better design would simply be this:

```
object MyClass {

    var editor: Editor = getDefaultEditor()

    fun getProject() = editor.project!!
    fun getDocument() = editor.document.charsSequence.toString().toLowerCase()
    fun getFindModel() = FindManager.getInstance(getProject()).findInFileModel.clone()
    fun getFindManager() = FindManager.getInstance(getProject())
}
```