# How to initialize a reference variable in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

In Java one can initialize a reference variable with null, for example a String variable can be initialized like so:

```
String str = null;
```

But in Kotlin, the point is to avoid using null as much as possible. So how can I initialize a property without using null

```
var str: String = ...
```

Comment: Use a non-null `String` value?

Comment: You can use `lateinit var` and `by lazy { ... }` to define a property which is only later initialized with a not null value. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623177/kotlin-property-initialization-using-by-lazy-vs-lateinit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point in Kotlin isn't to never use `null` (and nullable types), but rather to use it safely with convenient language constructs instead of fearing it. While using non-nullable types as much as possible is ideal, you don't have to always avoid them, that's why the various `null` handling constructs (safe calls, the Elvis operator, etc) exist.

If you can delay creating your variable until you have something to assign to it, that's a solution. If you can't, then marking it nullable and assigning `null` to it is perfectly fine, because the compiler will protect you from doing dangerous things with it.

Answer (score 6):

user `lateinit` keywords.Need to use, and then initialize

```
private lateinit var str : String
fun myInit(){
    str = "something";
}
```

Note : that accessing the uninitialized `lateinit` property results in an `UninitializedPropertyAccessException`.

However, `lateinit` does not support basic data types, such as `Int`.

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
var str: String

...

str = "Some Awesome Value"
```

if you want it nullable you can do

```
var str: String?
```

Comment: xtra credit for using the word "Awesome" in your code.

Answer (score 0):

As an option:

```
var str: String by Delegates.NotNull()
```