# Access Val in inner method

Tags: android, kotlin

I have following code :

```
val fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container)
                as SearchFragment? ?: searchFragment.also {
            addFragmentToActivity(it, R.id.fragment_container)

            search_view.setOnQueryTextListener(object : android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
                override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String): Boolean {
                    fragment.searchViewClicked(query)
                    return true
                }

                override fun onQueryTextChange(query: String): Boolean {
                    if (query.isEmpty()) {
                        fragment.clearList()
                    } else {
                        fragment.searchViewClicked(query)
                    }
                    return true
                }
            })
```

As you see I want to access `fragment` variable in `onQueryTextSubmit` and `onQueryTextChange`. But with current code I get `unresolved reference` error on fragment.

Could you let me know how should I fix the code?

Comment: not sure, but try this one.. this@ActivityName.fragment...

Comment: Simply get rid of `also` and put the body of the lambda directly into the method where this code is contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of :

```
val fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container)
                as SearchFragment? ?: searchFragment.also {
            addFragmentToActivity(it, R.id.fragment_container)
            ...
}
```

I should use :

```
val fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container)
                    as SearchFragment? ?: searchFragment.also {
                addFragmentToActivity(it, R.id.fragment_container)
             }
    ... // Continue of code
```

Answer (score 0):

fragment is used within its assignment statement.
i.e. fragment does not exist until the assignment is over.
split the declaration/assignment and usage separately, that should fix the code.

Answer (score 0):

Make a fragment object a class variable like this

```
private val fragment = FragmenLogin()
```

or use lateinit initialization

```
private lateinit var fragment: FragmentLogin
```

then you can use fragment object anywhere in the class (after it get initialized)

for more detail on lateinit see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36623703/5057663