# Why does the author design localCacheBillingClient as lateinit?

Tags: kotlin

The **Code A** is from the project `play-billing-samples`, you can see [it](https://github.com/android/play-billing-samples/blob/master/TrivialDriveKotlin/app/src/main/java/com/kotlin/trivialdrive/billingrepo/BillingRepository.kt).

I don't know why the author design `localCacheBillingClient` as `lateinit`, it cause the code is little complex, `if (::localCacheBillingClient.isInitialized == false) {...}` are invoked many times.

I think **Code B** can works well, right?

**Code A**

```
class BillingRepository private constructor(private val application: Application) :
        PurchasesUpdatedListener, BillingClientStateListener {

     lateinit private var localCacheBillingClient: LocalBillingDb


    val subsSkuDetailsListLiveData: LiveData<List<AugmentedSkuDetails>> by lazy {
        if (::localCacheBillingClient.isInitialized == false) {
            localCacheBillingClient = LocalBillingDb.getInstance(application)
        }
        localCacheBillingClient.skuDetailsDao().getSubscriptionSkuDetails()
    }

    val inappSkuDetailsListLiveData: LiveData<List<AugmentedSkuDetails>> by lazy {
        if (::localCacheBillingClient.isInitialized == false) {
            localCacheBillingClient = LocalBillingDb.getInstance(application)
        }
        localCacheBillingClient.skuDetailsDao().getInappSkuDetails()
    }

   fun startDataSourceConnections() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "startDataSourceConnections")
        instantiateAndConnectToPlayBillingService()
        localCacheBillingClient = LocalBillingDb.getInstance(application)
    }
    ...
}
```

**Code B**

```
class BillingRepository private constructor(private val application: Application) :
        PurchasesUpdatedListener, BillingClientStateListener {

    private val localCacheBillingClient: LocalBillingDb by lazy {
         LocalBillingDb.getInstance(application)
    }

    val subsSkuDetailsListLiveData: LiveData<List<AugmentedSkuDetails>> by lazy {
        localCacheBillingClient.skuDetailsDao().getSubscriptionSkuDetails()
    }


    val inappSkuDetailsListLiveData: LiveData<List<AugmentedSkuDetails>> by lazy {
        localCacheBillingClient.skuDetailsDao().getInappSkuDetails()
    }

   fun startDataSourceConnections() {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "startDataSourceConnections")
        instantiateAndConnectToPlayBillingService()        
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Don't know man, why author liked to use the lateinit and reflections. I'd go with the lazy property as well. Use lateinit only for the external initialization only. https://stackoverflow.com/q/36623177/11377112

Comment: You can only guess why the person who wrote that code chose that approach. I personally agree that it misuses `lateinit`, but that's my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kotlin - Property initialization using "by lazy" vs. "lateinit"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623177/kotlin-property-initialization-using-by-lazy-vs-lateinit?rq=1)

I believe the answer lies in this thread and precisely below point.

lateinit var can be initialized from anywhere the object is seen from, e.g. from inside a framework code, and multiple initialization scenarios are possible for different objects of a single class. by lazy { ... }, in turn, defines the only initializer for the property, which can be altered only by overriding the property in a subclass. If you want your property to be initialized from outside in a way probably unknown beforehand, use lateinit.

Comment: You missed the real one - the last point made in that answer is really the reason to avoid using `lazy` and prefer `lateinit` as the author did in code `A`. Basically in code `B`, if the `localCacheBillingClient` is never used, it will retain a reference to `application` and thus cause memory leaks when the application is killed.