# Kotlin lazy lateinit, in the context of run time safety

Tags: android, kotlin

I have been using both of them, both of them provide safety for `NullPointerException` but the `lateinit` can cause `UnInitializedPropetyException`, So which of these two is safer. What is the best use case for each of them, when the `lateinit` best fits and when `lazy` best fits?

The point I am trying to make is based on

1. Safety      //`lateinit` saves from NPE but it can throw `UnInitializedPropetyException`
2. Optimality

Is not it better to go for `lazy`, when one does not really need mutable property?

What is the usefulness of `lateinit`?

when `lateinit var abc:Def` can give `UnInitializedPropetyException` and
`var abc:Def?=null` can give `NPE`, in both cases we have mutability and exception.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin - Property initialization using "by lazy" vs. "lateinit"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623177/kotlin-property-initialization-using-by-lazy-vs-lateinit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They have two different purposes:

1. `by lazy` is for initialising something only if it is accessed runtime at some point. Consider a costly/resource intensive component or initialisation. If this component is used only in certain cases, `by lazy` can help with avoiding these costly initialisations
2. `lateinit` is more of a convenience method if you can't initialise something right away. For ex. in android if you want to save out a reference to one of your views, you can only initialise them in your `onCreateView`/`onViewCreated`. Unfortunately `lateinit` works with `var`s only, so it doesn't enforce immutability, so use it with caution :)

**Update:**
Both with `lateinit` and with the nullability pattern you get mutability & unsafety, so in this sense they are not so different.

But `lateinit` is a lot more verbose in the sense that you know if something goes wrong it's an initialisation problem (or it should be).
The nullability pattern is okay for more general problems, for ex: if you plan on clearing/resetting a component

Comment: (+1) with one tiny quibble - it's not so much a "convenience" but a necessity given the combination of (a) how Kotlin handles `val` assignments, and (b) the requirement for deferred initialization that some libraries/frameworks impose (such as Android, as you pointed out)

Comment: @homerman agreed, I was referring to the convenience of using it instead of nullables

Comment: @NagyRobi, Please enlighten me based on the added information to the quesiton

Answer (score 1):

`lazy` is safest because you need assign a value to it first and don't worry about initial state. Beside, about the resource, when first use `lazy` object, it is initialized. About performance, the result is saved in memory when you call get() first and then each get() call give result from memory.

About best case use them `late init` and `lazy`

- `late init` use in case you not sure about the way which object is
  initialized and mutability
- `lazy` use in case, you want only instance object exist in class
  scope and immutability

Answer (score 0):

- > When to use which one?

  lateinit can only be used with var (mutable)properties whereas lazy can only be used for val (immutable)properties.
  lateinit don’t work with primitive type.
  While using Singleton Pattern (Object Declaration in Kotlin) we should use lazy, as it will be initialized upon first use.
  In lateinit the type of the property must be non-null.
  lateinit can only be used when the property does not have a custom getter or setter.
  In lateinit var, it depends on the user to initialize the property properly in multi-threaded environments. Initialization by lazy { … } is thread-safe by default and make sure initialization is done at most once.

  ```
    var — Declared as mutable
    val — Read-only (immutable)

    val someText: String by lazy { "Variable is lazy initialized" }
    fun doPrintSomeText() {
    println("Length is  " + someText.length) // someText will be initialized here
    }

    lateinit var someText: String // initialize laterfun doPrintSomeText() {
    someText = "Variable is lateinit" // initialize 
    println("Length is  " + someText.length)
    }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if `lateinit` var is initialized or not before using it

```
lateinit var foo: Foo
if(::foo.isInitialized) {
    // foo is initialized. Go Ahead
}
```

When you know the var will be needed but not at the time of class loading, then You can declare it with `lateinit`. This means You will initialize it as per your need.

By lazy indicates that the variable is going to be initialized at the time of its first usage. And If you do not need to use that variable then it will not initialize at all.

And this will not result in NPE in any way.

In short, If we declare it as `lateinit`, then its tottally our duty as a developer to initialize it before using it