# What is the application of "by lazy" in Android-Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

In which places should the `by lazy` be used?

Why should it be used?

How does it make the code better

for example:

```
val currentResult: MutableLiveData<String> by lazy {
          MutableLiveData<String>()
}
```

Comment: does this answer help?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623177/kotlin-property-initialization-using-by-lazy-vs-lateinit

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> In which places should the by lazy be used?

They should be used where you don't need unnecessary initialization of the variables. These are `val` properties, so after initialization, that same object would be used in the whole run of the class.

> Why should it be used?

`lazy` should be used when any of your `objects` are heavy and they take a long time to initialize. Here `lazy` properties can help to skip that delay which could be caused by the initialization of those objects. As `lazy` would only initialize the variable when it is called, otherwise it won't be created.

> How does it make the code better

By lazily loading heavy objects, it increases the performance of the code, as any delay in the loading, which could've been caused due to the initialization of these heavy variables is now eliminated. It keeps the memory free, as these won't be initialized until the moment, they are called by the code.