# How to deal with non initialized lateinit vars

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-null-safety, kotlin-lateinit

I'm migrating a project from java to kotlin, and that project used a lot of variables that can be null and they are not initialized until some interaction with the user or external jobs have been done.

I'm trying to use kotlin null safety advantages, and I'm trying to avoid the use of `null` in the source code, so i'm dealing with all the variables using `lateinit`, like this: `lateinit var location: Location` instead of using `var location: Location? = null`

I'm doing it to avoid using `?` each time I need to use those variables. The issue now is... what happens if the variables has been not initialized?

For example, what happens if I need to call `location.getX()` in some part of the code? How to deal with cases in which location is still not initialized?

I figured out to deal with it using this:

```
if (!this::location.isInitialized){
    location.getX()
}
```

But then, I'm filling the code with that boilerplate code of isInitialized etc... so... at the end, I prefeer the old java version of the project without null safety, it's more clear and short.

If I come back to `var location: Location? = null`, then, I need to use

```
location.let {
    it.getX()
}
```

or

```
location?.getX()
```

and in this second case I'm still dealing with null, that is something I was trying to avoid

Is something I'm doing wrong? must I come back to null variables and `var location: Location? = null` instead of using `lateinit`? Exists a better approach to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have a wrong concept of how to use null in Kotlin. It is precisely because of Kotlin’s null safety features that you can safely make properties nullable. If something is not available at all times, it *should* be nullable. You are misusing `lateinit` in a way that makes your properties unsafe by forcing you to remember to check if they are initialized, the same way you always have to remember to check if fields are null in Java. So you have re-introduced the same problem that Kotlin null-safety solved.

If something is sometimes not available, it is perfectly appropriate to make it nullable. Kotlin’s null-safety features will ensure you don’t forget to check this possible state.

More reading here, from the Kotlin design lead: [Null is your friend](https://elizarov.medium.com/null-is-your-friend-not-a-mistake-b63ff1751dd5)

`lateinit` should only ever be used by properties that can never be null after `onCreate()`.

——

Maybe what you’re asking is how to more concisely check null on the Location without having to deal with its inner properties still being nullable? Aside from the `?.let` pattern, you can use this:

```
val location = location ?: return

// you can now freely use non-null location in this function
// from the local reference known to be non-null
```

The `?.let` case is much like the `if (x != null)` pattern in Java, except that it is also safe for properties that might be changed in multiple threads.

```
location?.let { location ->
    // freely use location.getX() and getY() inside the braces
}
```

Between these two patterns, you always have code that is just as concise as the Java way of checking it.

Comment: I edited my post, I miswrite some sample of code

Comment: If you want to go back to the Java way of being unsafe, then you can use `lateinit` and just let it crash with UnitializedPropertyAccessException in the same situations you would have received NullPointerException in Java.

Comment: I added an edit. I think maybe I understand what you’re asking now.

Answer (score 1):

`lateinit` should only ever be used for cases when they variable is guaranteed to be initialized, it's just not possible to verify this guarantee at compile time. A good example is `Activity.onCreate`: while the Kotlin compiler has no way of knowing that a field initialized in `onCreate` is guaranteed to not be null in `onResume`, it's a pretty strong contract in the Android SDK, so it's reasonable to use `lateinit` for that field and avoid null-checks.

For anything that's not guaranteed to be non-null at access time, stick to nullable types and do null-checks as usual. For anything that's guaranteed to be non-null, use `lateinit` without any extra checks: if those call-sites lead to crashes, remove `lateinit` and change the type to nullable.

Answer (score 0):

you can simplify x?.let {}

change:

```
location.let {
    it.getX()
}
```

to:

```
location?.getX()
```

And set a default value like:

```
val x = location?.getX() ?: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm migrating a project from java to kotlin, and that project used a lot of variables that can be null and they are not initialized until some interaction with the user or external jobs have been done.

You can use lazy initialization for properties that need to wait for interaction.

```
foo: MyType by lazy { ... }
```

There is a post about that [Property initialization using "by lazy" vs. "lateinit"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36623177/property-initialization-using-by-lazy-vs-lateinit)

As Egor pointed out, lateinit should be used when you can warrant that a property will be initialized. Still you can check for initialization with:

```
this::myLateinitVar.isInitialized
```

But if your source code consists about nullables, then you should definitively back to nullable types in Kotlin and make use of the ? operator. After all, it's a tool there for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

The answers cover all the stuff, but I just wanted to address this bit: *"I prefeer the old java version of the project without null safety, it's more clear and short"* - the problem hasn't gone away in the Java version, it's just hidden. If you can't guarantee those properties are initialised, then whatever language you're writing in, if you try to access them before they're ready you're in trouble!

If you *can* guarantee they'll be initialised, use `lateinit`. If you *can't*, then you probably want to make them *nullable*, since "nothing there" is a potential state you need to handle wherever you access it.

You *can* use `this::myVariable.isInitialized`, but I feel like this is more of a situational thing, where there's some early setup that has to handle a potential *temporary* uninitialised state, but by the time that's finished it's guaranteed to have been set. If the main code can't rely on it being initialised, then I feel like making it *nullable* is the better choice, since that forces you to handle the possibility and it's just safer all-round. If you rely on `isInitialized` you might miss a point where you need to check it, since it's not enforced.

If the enforced null-safety handling is annoying, remember that it's the same situation in Java - it's just not warning you that what you're doing is dangerous and you need to handle it! If you're sure a thing isn't *null*, you can add `!!` after it to tell the null-safety system "don't worry, trust me, I *know* it's not null". There are some rare occasions where this is true and you do know more than the system - but most people only use it to disable the null-safety system and ignore the problem though, and end up with brittle and potentially broken code. It's there to help!