# More fun with Kotlin delegates

Tags: delegates, kotlin, android-lifecycle, android-databinding

If you know Google's experimental Android Architecture Components, you probably know `MutableLiveData`. Trying to make it a bit more fun to use I came with:

```
class KotlinLiveData<T>(val default: T) {
    val data = MutableLiveData<T>()

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>):T {
        return data.value ?: default
    }

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value:T) {
        if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {
            data.value = value
        } else {
            data.postValue(value)
        }
    }
}
```

And then I can:

```
var name : String by KotlinLiveData("not given")
name = "Chrzęszczybrzęczykiewicz"
```

But alas - that makes `data` which is needed i.e. to register `Observer` inaccessible:

```
name.data.observe(this, nameObserver) // won't work :(
```

Any idea if I can get it somehow?

Comment: Consider posting your solution as an answer not as an update to your question. This will help future readers and avoid confusion. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [access the delegate object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896314/access-property-delegate-in-kotlin) of the property and get the `MutableLiveData<T>` from it:

```
inline fun <reified R> KProperty<*>.delegateAs<R>(): R? {
    isAccessible = true
    return getDelegate() as? R
}
```

Then the usage is:

```
::name.delegateAs<KotlinLiveData<String>>?.data?.observe(this, nameObserver)
```

<sup>To reference a member property, use `this::name` or `someInstance::name`.</sup>

This solution requires you to add the Kotlin reflection API, [`kotlin-reflect`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect),  as a dependency to your project. Also, due to the type erasure, the `.delegateAs<KotlinLiveData<String>>` call is not type-safe: it can only check that the delegate is `KotlinLiveData<*>` but not that its type argument is `String`.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to hotkey's solution, here's some better code:

```
class KotlinLiveData<T>(val default: T, val liveData : MutableLiveData<T>? = null) {
    val data = liveData ?: MutableLiveData<T>()

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>):T {
        return data.value ?: default
    }

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value:T) {
        if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {
            data.value = value
        } else {
            data.postValue(value)
        }
    }
}

inline fun <reified R> KMutableProperty0<*>.getLiveData(): MutableLiveData<R> {
    isAccessible = true
    return (getDelegate() as KotlinLiveData<R>).data
}

inline fun <reified R> KMutableProperty0<*>.observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, obs : Observer<R>) {
    isAccessible = true
    (getDelegate() as KotlinLiveData<R>).data.observe(owner,obs)
}
```

Now I can:

`someViewModel::name.observe(myActivity, Observer<String>{...})`

with

`someViewModel.name = "Kowalski, Leon"`

working as expected

This class enables using LiveData with Android Data Binding out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

the simplest way you can achieve is make the delegator to a field, for example:

```
@JvmField val dataOfName =  KotlinLiveData("not given")
var name : String by dataOfName
```

then you can using live data in the class, for example:

```
dataOfName.data.observe(this, nameObserver)
name = "Chrzęszczybrzęczykiewicz"
```

**OR** you can write some syntax suglar, for example:

```
var name : String by live("not given").observe(this, nameObserver)
```

**Note** you can make `nameObserver` lazily too, for example:

```
val observers by lazy{mutableListOf<Observer>()}
var name : String by live("not given").observe(this){data->
    observers.forEach{it.dataChanged(data)}
}
```

then you can do something like as below:

```
observers+= nameObserver;

name = "Chrzęszczybrzęczykiewicz"

observers-= nameObserver;
```

Comment: First suggestion won't allow `name="something"` as it expects `KotlinLiveData<String>`. Second suggestion would of course work, but it is completely impractical, since I need to register observers for that value in many different places in code...

Comment: @ssuukk why the first approach can't? you can lazy the `nameObserver` in the second approach  too. the first approach the `name` property type is a `String`.