# Access Kotlin Delegate Type without an Instance

Tags: reflection, properties, delegates, kotlin

I have read [Access property delegate in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30896314/3755692) which is about accessing a delegate from an instance. One can use `KProperty::getDelegate` since Kotlin 1.1, however this will return the instance of the delegate and therefore needs an instance of the class first.

Now I want to get the type of the delegate without having an instance of the class. Consider a library with a custom delegate type `CustomDelegate` that want's to get all properties of a class that are delegated to an instance of `CustomDelegate`:

```
class Example
{
    var nonDelegatedProperty = "I don't care about this property"
    var delegatedProperty1 by lazy { "I don't care about this too" }
    var delegatedProperty2 by CustomDelegate("I care about this one")
}
```

How can I, given I have `KClass<Example>`, but not an instance of `Example`, get all properties delegated to `CustomDelegate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I, given I have KClass<Example>, but not an instance of
>   Example, get all properties delegated to CustomDelegate?

You can do it in two ways depending on your needs.

First of all, you have to include the *kotlin-reflect* dependency in your `build.gradle` file:

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.1.51"
```

In my opinion, you should use the first solution if you can, because it's the most clear and optimized one. The second solution instead, can handle one case that the first solution can't.

**First**

You can loop an the declared properties and check if the type of the property or the type of the delegate is `CustomDelegate`.

```
// Loop on the properties of this class.
Example::class.declaredMemberProperties.filter { property ->
    // If the type of field is CustomDelegate or the delegate is an instance of CustomDelegate,
    // it will return true.
    CustomDelegate::class.java == property.javaField?.type
}
```

There's only one problem with this solution, you will get also the fields with type `CustomDelegate`, so, given this example:

```
class Example {
    var nonDelegatedProperty = "I don't care about this property"
    val delegatedProperty1 by lazy { "I don't care about this too" }
    val delegatedProperty2 by CustomDelegate("I care about this one")
    val customDelegate = CustomDelegate("jdo")
}
```

You will get `delegatedProperty2` and `customDelegate`. If you want to get only `delegatedProperty2`, I found an horrible solution that you can use if you need to manage this case.

**Second**

If you check the source code of `KPropertyImpl`, you can see how a delegation is implemented. So, you can do something like this:

```
// Loop on the properties of this class.
Example::class.declaredMemberProperties.filter { property ->
    // You must check in all superclasses till you find the right method.
    property::class.allSuperclasses.find {
        val computeField = try {
            // Find the protected method "computeDelegateField".
            it.declaredFunctions.find { it.name == "computeDelegateField" } ?: return@find false
        } catch (t: Throwable) {
            // Catch KotlinReflectionInternalError.
            return@find false
        }

        // Get the delegate or null if the delegate is not present.
        val delegateField = computeField.call(property) as? Field
        // If the delegate was null or the type is different from CustomDelegate, it will return false.
        CustomDelegate::class.java == delegateField?.type
    } != null
}
```

In this case, you will get only `delegatedProperty2` as result.

Comment: Using the first solution, is it possible to map the delegated field and the delegate field? Since my delegated properties must all inherit from one interface, this would make it easy to return only `delegatedProperty2`

Comment: @msrd0 Yes, you can. You can change the condition: `CustomDelegate::class.java == property.javaField?.type` to the condition `CustomDelegate::class.java == property.javaField?.type && property.returnType.isSubtypeOf(MyInterface::class.starProjectedType)`